# How to go to another link if you are currently in a subdirectory?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, routes, react-router, router

If your in the directory say (test.com/dir1/subdir), then if i click on dir2 the link is going to (test.com/dir1/dir2). How can i go to (test.com/dir2) by using routes?

Comment: Can you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to backtrack the file path.

**Current Directory**: (test.com/dir1/subdir)

command `"../../dir2"`

Comment: Ok I.m taking here about reactjs